# Image upload does not accept many of commons.wikimedia.org URL's

Tags: feature-request, bug

[image]

Image upload does not accept *many* of `commons.wikimedia.org` URL's

Example: `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7a/Gehling_PLZ106AR_Kruk_OTT_2013_D7N9017_009.jpg/640px-Gehling_PLZ106AR_Kruk_OTT_2013_D7N9017_009.jpg`

I understand it's powered by imgur, can we ask them to accommodate the request?

Comment: Why do you need to upload to imgur if its on wikicommons? Just to preserve the image in case wikicommons changes their url's?

Comment: @Jamiec - correct

Comment: When you see the image, right-click and select "display image" (or equivalent), the true image will be displayed, copy the actual image url. The first url is the one of a container. Alternatively drag the image from the container to your desktop, and upload it by dragging it again from your desktop into the imgur popup above.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a bug.  There are two issues here:

1. The link you're trying is not a direct link to the file.  It's a server-generated thumbnail.  Have a closer look at the path of the link.  You will notice it shows the file name twice.
2. The file size is 2.18 MB, larger than the max upload limit of 2MB.

In this case, the link that *should* work is:
`https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7a/Gehling_PLZ106AR_Kruk_OTT_2013_D7N9017_009.jpg`  However, it still won't work because the source file is too large.

Normally, on wikicommons, you will find a link for direct file links that will work here:
[image]

It will provide you everything you need to share the image with proper credits:
[image]

The link you need to upload the image is the File URL, but again, in this case the you will need to reduce its file size first.

Answer (score 1):

It's been fixed! The [latest imgur update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301856/sizing-suffixes-on-uploads-broken/301882#301882) to SE must have fixed it.

[image]